# How we can Schedule Notifications on the same day at multiple time slots using Alarm Manager or Flutter Local notifications?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-notifications, background-service

I want to schedule notifications as an alarm that should trigger on different time on the same day. Whenever i am Scheduling multiple notifications, Alarm Only fires the latest notification and discard all the previous schedules. I am Using Alarm Manager with Flutter Local notification. Also this is all happening in background.

I have tried Android Alarm Manager android_alarm_manager_plus plugin and Flutter local notifications to schedule multiple notifications on the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a unique id for each notification

Comment: Thankyou, it somehow solved my problem of getting multiple notifications by scheduling on different time stamps. but still I have an issue that those scheduled timestamps have the same information like the latest information.

Comment: If you are using Awesome notifications package then you also need to have a unique name for the channel name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

[flutter pub get package](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)